# IPAddress.Parse("localhost") throws error

Tags: c#

I have a service that takes an ip string and tries to parse it to an `IPAdress`. Some external services might pass in `127.0.0.1` but there are some passing in `localhost`, which causes problems.

So the first one works but the second one throws an error

```
try 
{
    var foo = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
} 
catch 
{
    Console.WriteLine("parsing failed for foo");
}
        
try 
{
    var bar = IPAddress.Parse("localhost");
} 
catch 
{
    Console.WriteLine("parsing failed for bar");
}
```

Do I have to check if the ip string equals `localhost` or is there something I can use for it?

Comment: `localhost` isn't an IP address.... why not just check for this special case (e.g. `if (string.Equals(ip, "localhost", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) { ip = "127.0.0.1";  }`)?

Comment: that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Localhost is defined in the following file and can be different on each machine : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to resolve host names and IP Addresses, you can pass either to [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Dns_GetHostEntry_System_String_).

This will give you, in return, a list of possible IP addresses (if it was passed a host name) or a single IP Address (If it was passed an IP Address)

Comment: thanks but this does not work for me, I tried this code https://pastebin.com/STvD9a8f `                 IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipString); // any ip string from external service, e.g. "localhost"
                IPAddress[] ipAddresses = ipHostEntry.AddressList; // count is 2. second is 127.0.0.1
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipAddresses.First(); // {::1}
                // Ip address will be something like http://[::1]:1234`

Comment: @Olaf if your objection is IPv6 addresses, you could check the `AddressFamily` property and exclude them.